# Matlab: Full 3D-Rotation with elevation higher +/-90

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, rotation

when rotating a 3D-plot in Matlab one can only rotate completely, so full 360°, around the z-axis (azimuthal angle) but only from +/-90° around the x/y-axes (elevation angle). I know that this includes all possible views in a spherical coordinate system, yet, a customer of mine would like to have the same functionality like in Fiji (3D-Viewer) or similar 3D-Viewers, to rotate fully about the 360° around an arbitary axis.

As simple demo:

```
surf(peaks); rotate3d on
```

I thought of a handles listener with callback when the view changes and then adjusting the azimuthal and elevation angles accordingly to generate the feeling of a full rotation but maybe someone has a better and simpler idea :)

Cheers Mika

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution:

One can enable the camera control toolbar and use the camorbit functionality which does exactly what it should. In my GUI I just enable/disable it via a custom toggle button in the toolbar like so

```
if strcmp(get(handles.uitoggletool5,'State'),'on') == 1
    cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit');
else
    cameratoolbar('SetMode','nomode');
end
```